# How to mimic Echo sync mode using rsync commandline?

Tags: ubuntu, sync, rsync, synctoy

The MS tool SyncToy, has 3 intuitive sync modes (N.B. sync NOT backup), to sync two folders.

One of them is:

**Echo** which looks for changes (file modifications, new files, renames, deletes) in the left folder and makes them in the right folder (one-way sync).

I'm using internal GPT ext4 disks, ubuntu 12.04 LTS, for local sync.

**How to mimic Echo sync mode using rsync commandline ?**

Comment: I find rsync documentation confusing and contradictory, so I'm asking for the correct options to, on a daily basis syncing two folders, that  handles file modifications, new files, renames, deletes, in a sane way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `rsync` doesn't support this feature. This is on the feature request page of some site. Is has an option `--fuzzy`

```
          -y, --fuzzy

          This option tells rsync that it should look for a basis file for
          any destination file that is  missing.   The  current  algorithm
          looks in the same directory as the destination file for either a
          file that has an identical size and modified-time,  or  a  simi‐
          larly-named  file.  If found, rsync uses the fuzzy basis file to
          try to speed up the transfer.

          Note that the use of the --delete option might get  rid  of  any
          potential  fuzzy-match  files,  so  either use --delete-after or
          specify some filename exclusions if you need to prevent this.
```

## freefilesync

> Description:
>
> folder comparison and synchronization tool
>   This is a folder comparison and synchronization tool. It is optimized
>   for highest performance and usability without restricted or overloaded
>   UI interfaces.
>
> Features:
>   * Multiple folder pairs
>   * Batch capability
>   * Binary comparison
>   * Handle conflicts and propagate deletions
>   * Optimized performance
>   * Transactional file copy
>   * ...

**Mirror** option in **freefilesync**
There is an award winning cross platform app called **freefilesync**( http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/ ) with nice GUI. It has a **batch mode** will allow you to schedule sync. It's xml file that define left,right folders for sync. Using this feature you can use *freefilesync* from terminal.

Thus you can sync files and folders using

*GUI
*BASH script
*cron

Do to its superb features and ease of use and script support `FreeFileSync` can be used as an alternative to `rsync`

## Install

use PPA
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/getdeb_apps